# Change the title of storefront

Tags: saleor

I've checked out the latest stable release at tag `2.11.1`. As mentioned on `2.11.1` read-me file:

> - **saleor-storefront/src/index.html** - Main template file that contains the `<div id="root"></div>`
>   - Can change title of storefront here

I have changed the storefront title as suggested above and built by `npm run build`. Then deployed to a remote server.

#### Problem

For a brief moment, the storefront title is actually set as I desire:

[image: Screenshot_20210725_205631]

However, after a moment, the title reverts back to:

[image: Screenshot_20210725_210439]

What am I missing?

#### Only home page

When I navigate to any page except home page, the title is set to the one I have inside `src/core/config.ts` file. But navigating to the home page, results in the above problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved!

Saleor dashboard allows to change the storefront title by the `Name of your store` input field of `CONFIGURATION > Site Settings`:

[image: Saleor dashboard]

Answer (score 0):

Even after changing name of the store in site settings still persisting the same issue.

Comment: Did you modify `saleor-storefront/src/index.html` and `src/core/config.ts` too?